# How do you http-auth all sites on a server?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, http-authentication

I'm setting up a development server and need to apply these basic rules to all virtual hosts on the server in the `/var/www/html` directory.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Development Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I simply tried to put it in my `httpd.conf`, However apache throws an error when checking the syntax: `AuthType not allowed here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Authentication always applies to a ***context***; this may be a VirtualHost, a Directory, or a Location.

```
<Location />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Development Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Location />
```

Comment: Many thanks, after some investigation I need this to work only on sites in the `/var/www/html` directory, is that possible? (also you don't need the `/` in the closing tag)

Comment: THanks I've worked it out, just needed to use `<Directory>`

Comment: Refer to the documentation for details on how these directives interact with each other: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/sections.html#file-and-web